# What is the difference between panic and process::exit

Tags: rust

As per the title, what is the difference between these two and when should I consider using one over the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There may or may not be a difference depending on your definition of what happens when a panic happens (defined in `Cargo.toml`). Depending on whether you have it set to `unwind` or `abort`, different things will happen:

- With `unwind`, this will (as the name suggests) unwind the stack. With this, in particular, it is possible to get a full stack trace
- With `abort`, you will only get the last callee

`process::exit()`, on the other hand, is a "clean" exit - you will not get a last callee, and you'll get a regular process exit status.

Due to this, you'll ideally want to keep to the following:

- For planned shutdowns, use `exit()`. Do note that a known error is considered a planned shutdown
- For unplanned shutdowns (i.e. exceptional failures) consider `panic!()`, as you'll both benefit from being able to get a stack trace when this happens, and the failure case should be exceptional enough that it is effectively unaccounted for and stems from an unplanned scenario

Answer (score 2):

Afaik, a panic is never supposed to happen in a released program. It gives informations for developpers, but not anything user friendly. I'd say "use it for errors that should not happen in prod". There is probably behind something like an `exit(101);`

exit just terminates your process with the code you give to it. An `exit(0)` should mean "Everything is okay".